# tf tutorial is displaying just one turtle instead of two

Tags: transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am learning tf and doing the tf tutorials (py), In this tutorial:

http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Tutorials/Writing%20a%20tf%20listener%20%28Python%29

when I perform the command:

`$ roslaunch learning_tf start_demo.launch`

I am supposed to see two turtles, but I see only one. I've double checked the instructions and it seems all is correct. What I don't see is where the second turtle's starting position is indicated. Could it be that the second turtle is on top of the first one which is why I don't see it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/280412/tf-tutorial-is-displaying-just-one-turtle-instead-of-two/) by [pitosalas](https://answers.ros.org/users/30692/pitosalas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 628 on 2018-01-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello @pitosalas,

My guess is that you forgot to add the listener node tag to the launch file.

After the instruction:

> **2. Running the listener**
> With your text editor, open the launch file
> called start_demo.launch, and add the
> following lines:

It must to be like that:

```
<launch>
    <!-- Turtlesim Node-->
    <node pkg="turtlesim" type="turtlesim_node" name="sim"/>
    <node pkg="turtlesim" type="turtle_teleop_key" name="teleop" output="screen"/>

    <node name="turtle1_tf_broadcaster" pkg="learning_tf" type="turtle_tf_broadcaster.py" respawn="false" output="screen" >
      <param name="turtle" type="string" value="turtle1" />
    </node>
    <node name="turtle2_tf_broadcaster" pkg="learning_tf" type="turtle_tf_broadcaster.py" respawn="false" output="screen" >
      <param name="turtle" type="string" value="turtle2" /> 
    </node>
    <node pkg="learning_tf" type="turtle_tf_listener.py" name="listener" />
  </launch>
```

The `turtle_tf_listener` is the node that spawns the second turtle (lines **16** and **17**)

```
  16     spawner = rospy.ServiceProxy('spawn', turtlesim.srv.Spawn)
  17     spawner(4, 2, 0, 'turtle2')
```

Hope it can help you!

Cheers

---

Originally posted by [marcoarruda](https://answers.ros.org/users/25735/marcoarruda/) with karma: 541 on 2018-01-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1